# How to change the multitasking view in iOS 9?

Tags: iphone, settings, ios, multitasking

So I just made the jump from iOS 7 to 9 (I know, big jump) and I'm already thrown off by the switched multitasking view. I don't mind the overlapping idea, but the big difference is that the apps extend to the left now instead of to the right. Is there any way at all (without jailbreaking) to change the multitasking view in iOS 9 so that the open apps extend to the right instead of to the left? Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No, not without jailbreaking.

If you're willing to jailbreak your phone, there is a tweak called [SwitcherTweak](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/10/19/switchertweak/) (no idea how they came up with the name) which lets you select which direction the app switcher goes in.

(Note: if you have updated to iOS 9.1, there's no jailbreak utility currently available for it and there is [no way to downgrade](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214295/12285).)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It's sad that it's not possible to downgrade our iOS anymore--I guess it follows right along with Apple's business model though.